# Что-то не так с CMakeList.txt в Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, cmake

Настроил CMakeList.txt в Android Studio, все работало. Включил параллельно второй тестовый проект, чтобы попробовать и разобраться с новыми инструментами. Возвращаюсь в основной проект и там все полетело. Ниже приведен текст ошибки и CMakeList.txt
[image: Ошибка]

[image: CMakeList.txt (1)]
[image: CMakeList.txt (2)]

Comment: Долой картинки!!! - Текстом выкладывайте

Comment: У Вас директория содержит пробел (`.../Android project/...`), а потому директорией компиляции считается `.../Android`, а оставшаяся ее часть - другим аргументом. Так что Вам необходимо обеспечить следующее: директория должна передаваться обрамлённой в двойные кавычки

Comment: Или переименовать папку/проект, чтобы не было пробела.